# nondeterministic failures due to incorrect malloc size?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, malloc, non-deterministic

Do we have an example that demonstrates non-deterministic failures due to the incorrect malloc size in C?

For example, in my 'gzip' program in linux:

```
.
.
.
char* a = (char*)malloc(256) // correct version 
is changed to
char* a = (char*)malloc(206) //faulty version
.
.
.
```

Because of this, a test case tc that pass on the correct version becomes fail (i.e., segmentation fault) on the faulty version.
However, the failure is non-deterministic. Sometimes, the failed test case tc on the faulty version does not cause segmentation fault (i.e., pass).

This may be due to the 'undefined' behavior of malloc, but I could not know how it happens exactly.

Does anyone can give me some concrete example?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the memory as a sequence of pages. Some are available to your process, some are unavailable due to permissions and some are simply inaccessible, i.e. not mapped in. Consider this map (not to scale):

```
      +                        +   +
      |   Page, 4096 bytes     |   |
      +-----------------+------+   |
      |                 |      |   |
      |                 |      |   |
      |                 |      |   |
      +-----------------+------+-->v
           3890B          206B   X <-- Not mapped, can't touch!
```

If you allocate 206 bytes it all depends where in the page those 206 bytes will lie.

- If they lie at the start (to the left) accessing more is OK as far as
  Linux is concerned (but still undefined behavior as far as C is concerned)
- If however accessing more bytes **spills into another page**, with a different
  protection or into one that's not mapped in, Linux will not be amused and you'll get a segfault

So you're at the mercy of something you can't control: where `malloc` will allocate your data, i.e. where the additional 50 bytes will be.

Comment: @freddy Don't accept it just yet, maybe better stuff comes up.

Answer (score 1):

It is not undefined behaviour of the malloc. It simply gives you the memory you asked for.

You probably access non-reserved memory later (something like `a[208] = 'x';`) which WILL cause the undefined behaviour.

C Standard says:

> **undefined behavior**
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
> for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

Which means **anything** can happen. You cannot predict the result, and must always avoid such situations.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the 'undefined behaviour'? How it can cause failure non-deterministically?

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) Here you can read more about UB.